# Access AWS Tags inside ECS docker containers

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am creating a ECS Service with a few resource tags through a cloudformation template. Once the service is up and running, is there a way I can access these aws tags from within the container?

I was thinking if there is a way to make them available as environment variables in the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run one of the following command from within the container:

#### list-tags-for-resource CLI commands with task ARN [3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/list-tags-for-resource.html)

```
aws ecs list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<Account_Number>:task/test/186de825c8EXAMPLE10bf1c3bb142
```

#### list-tags-for-resource CLI commands with service ARN [3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/list-tags-for-resource.html)

```
aws ecs list-tags-for-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<Account_Number>:service/test/service
```